# VB.NET LINQ WHERE query collection with various keys throws KeyNotFoundException

Tags: vb.net, linq, exception, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.8

I would like to select first element from collection using LINQ WHERE function and lambda, **but some elements doesn't have subjected key** (only one of them has it) - and so I'm receiving KeyNotFoundException error... ;-/
[see collection structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysTdd.png)

Is there any way how to solve it?

`views.First(Function(x) x("DefaultView").ToString = "TRUE")`
... threw an exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'

Thanks. #JK

Comment: Why not check the value of the key instead of trying to access the key?

Comment: Do you mean to iterate over all of them and check if current element has the right key? Or somehow else?

Comment: in your lambda, instead of doing `x("DefaultView")` which would error is that key isn't there, simply check if the key is what you want with `x.Key = "DefaultView"` and then check the value `x.Value = ...` . Also consider using `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`

Comment: good tip, but how should I retype it to be able to use it? simple `x.Key` is not available and `views.Where(function(x as generic.KeyValuePair(Of string, object)) x.key = "DefaultView")` doesn't work as well :-(

Comment: I just noticed that your `views` is actually a list of Dictionaries. I initially thought you were dealing with a single Dictionary. Do you know which Dictionary in the list you are accessing or are you searching all Dictionaries?

Comment: yes, you are right, its list of dictionaries... and I need to search all of them...

Comment: Ok, and for your result, you want to return the dictionary in the list that contains defaultview as true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid double lookup in the dictionary.

```
views.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) 
                        Dim value
                        Return x.TryGetValue("DefaultView", value) AndAlso value.ToString() = "TRUE"
                    End Function)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```vb
views.FirstOrDefault(Function(x As Dictionary(Of String, Object))
                         Return x.ContainsKey("DefaultView") AndAlso x("DefaultView").ToString() = "TRUE"
                     End Function)
```

`ContainsKey` ensures that the Key exists in the Dictionary.
`AndAlso` will only check the second condition if ContainsKey returns true
`x("DefaultView")` will no longer error because we know it exists